# A query regarding $E(\frac{X}{Y})$

Tags: expected-value

Given that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and $Y>0$ and $E(X)=0$. We wish to compute $E(\frac{X}{Y})$.

**The intended method**

Since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, it is obvious that $X$ and $\frac{1}{Y}$ are independent also. Thus 
$$E(\frac{X}{Y})=E(X\frac{1}{Y})=E(X)E(\frac{1}{Y})=0E(\frac{1}{Y})=0$$

However we could also supply the following method:

**Other Method**

Let $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$ then 
$$E(Z)=E(\frac{X}{Y})=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{y}f_Z(\frac{x}{y}) dz=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{y}\int_0^{\infty} y f_Y(y)f_X(zy)dydz $$
Now we have that 
$$x=zy\Rightarrow dx=ydz$$
So in the integral we obtain
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x}{y}\int_0^{\infty}  f_Y(y)f_X(x)dydx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_X(x)dx\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{y}f_Y(y)dy=E(X)E(\frac{1}{Y})=0$$

I am slightly unsure if this other method is entirely valid -- is this use of $dx=ydz$ entirely valid? I would have thought we need to use product rule since $y$ too is a function of $z$?

Is this method still correct?

Comment: You seem to replace $f_Z(\frac{x}{y})$ by $\int_0^{\infty}yf_Y(y)f_X(zy)dy$. But on base of what?

Comment: It is wrong to give proofs assuming existence of densities unless you are told explicitly that they exist.

Comment: drhab -- it is a known result.

Comment: With both methods, the key condition is that $E(1/Y)$ existw, that is, is finite.  If it is, both methods are OK.  If $E(1/Y)$ is not finite, both methods are wrong.

Comment: Is there a common example of when $E(1/Y)$ is infinite?